# How to get an oily mouth feel

Tags: mouthfeel

I'm putting together a stout that I want to have a sweet flavor and oily mouthfeel, however I don't particularly want to mash 20lbs of grain for a 5 gallon batch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: oily like hop resin, or oily like slick/smooth?

Comment: 1.5 quarts 5w30 thrown into the boil with 30 minutes left.

Comment: Describe oily.  That is generally a bad thing in normal beer descriptor terminology.  You must mean something else.  Perhaps you can give a commercial example of what you mean.

Comment: Oily like Ten Fidy or Older Viscosity.  Like a big stout that looks like motor oil and it thick like syrup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a thicker mouthfeel there are several options.

1. Flaked Oats or Barley will give a creamier, smoother mouthfeel.  These will need to be mashed with base malt.  Keep that in mind if you are an extract brewer.
2. Mash at a higher temp.  This results in more residual dextrins.  When done right the residual body can be quite noticable.  Done poorly and the beer will be overly sweet in the end.
3. Using Lactose can also create a creamy mouthfeel perception (1 lb/5 gal).  Results in a slightly sweet finish as well. Not point 2.

While I still don't call these things oily, I get your gist (I hope).
I think you'd be surprised that many of the beers where you experience this phenomenon do not have some sort of over the top recipe addition or technique change to the brewing process.  I well brewed big body stout will just happen on its own with a proper recipe and grain bill.

Comment: The mouthfeel of beer with oats is usually described as 'oily'. Some claim that rye can give the same feel, but 'oily' is usually associated with oats.

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of magical trick I wasn't already planning on using.  I'm also going to try to keep the FG up above 1.030-1.040.

Comment: I have alwyas found flaked barley or oats to give a thinner mouthfeel.  Try a blind side by side comparison to see for yourself.

Comment: 1.030-1.040 final gravity isn't really going to change your mouthfeel a whole lot its just going to be sweet I think.

Answer (score 1):

Rye malt does exactly what you describe.  Use 10-20% of your total grist as rye malt.

Comment: I wish I had seen this before I got my grain.  Next time around I will try it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add flaked oats to your recipe they will add a silky/oily texture to the beer.  You will only need about 1-2 pounds per 5 gallon batch depending on OG.  If you do use too many they can have an adverse affect on head retention.